# Invalid image src error

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

```
var nodeIconImg = new Image();
nodeIconImg.onload = function () {

    var nodeIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: nodeIconImg,
        width: 30,
        height: 30
    });
}

var url = '<?= $baseurl; ?>/img/' + node.main_photo;
nodeIconImg.src = url;
```

This is the core code line in kinetic.js where the error happens (exactly in the drawImage method):

```
drawImage: function () {
    var a = arguments,
        b = this._context;
    3 === a.length ? b.drawImage(a[0], a[1], a[2]) : 5 === a.length ? b.drawImage(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]) : 9 === a.length && b.drawImage(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8])
}
```

The error message is:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that
>   is not, or is no longer, usable.

Any ideas? Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your nodeIcon is not in scope after the onload function completes.

So later in your code when you try to use nodeIcon, it is no longer defined and throws the error.

You need to either declare `var nodeIcon` outside the onload function

```
var nodeIcon;

var nodeIconImg = new Image();
nodeIconImg.onload = function () {

    nodeIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: nodeIconImg,
        width: 30,
        height: 30
    });

}
var url = "ship.png";
nodeIconImg.src = url;
```

Or add nodeIcon to a layer inside the onload function

```
var nodeIconImg = new Image();
nodeIconImg.onload = function () {

    var nodeIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: nodeIconImg,
        width: 30,
        height: 30
    });
    layer.add(nodeIcon);
    layer.draw();

}
var url = "ship.png";
nodeIconImg.src = url;
```